# Why does only one of two virtualenvs hit "OpenSSL.SSL.Error: 'PEM routines', 'PEM_read_bio',... 'SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file'..."?

Tags: python, ssl, exception, pem, certifi

In the process of updating a virtualenv I seem to have gotten things out of whack in the ssl libraries or something. Code that previously worked in either of two virtualenvs now works in only one; in the one I changed the code shown below generates the subsequent error.

I don't see any obvious differences between the virtualenvs that seem relevant or that match what I've found in the numerous cases of similar issues. Can anyone suggest any other lines of investigation, or does anything obvious jump out?

In both envs we have

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

Here's the high level call to `requests.get()` and the gist of the SSL error. Further down I include a diff of `pip freeze` in the two envs.

```
response = requests.get(
    query,
    auth=(self.user, self.token),
    verify=True,
    cert=self._requests_ca_bundle
    )
```

Yields the error:

```
  File "/home/security/.virtualenvs/nimbus/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nimbus/gitter.py", line 338, in call_api
    cert=self._requests_ca_bundle
  File "/home/security/.virtualenvs/nimbus/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
...
  File "/home/security/.virtualenvs/nimbus/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 421, in load_cert_chain
    self._ctx.use_privatekey_file(keyfile or certfile)
  File "/home/security/.virtualenvs/nimbus/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 798, in use_privatekey_file
    self._raise_passphrase_exception()
...
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('PEM routines', 'PEM_read_bio', 'no start line'), ('SSL routines', 'SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file', 'PEM lib’)]
```

Here's the certs (from certifi) sent in each environment to `requests.get()` by the parameter `cert=self._requests_ca_bundle`; the diff is empty.

```
$ wc /tmp/*.cacert*
  5246  10849 321421 /tmp/b.cacert.pem
  5245  10849 321421 /tmp/s.cacert.pem
```

Here's a diff of the output of `pip freeze` in both virtualenvs.

```
This virtualenv works.              This virtualenv doesn't.

appdirs==1.4.3                    <
asn1crypto==0.22.0                  asn1crypto==0.22.0
                                  > awscli==1.11.66
                                  > botocore==1.5.29
certifi==2017.4.17                  certifi==2017.4.17
cffi==1.10.0                        cffi==1.10.0
chardet==3.0.4                      chardet==3.0.4
                                  > colorama==0.3.7
cryptography==1.8.1                 cryptography==1.8.1
cssselect==1.0.1                    cssselect==1.0.1
cssutils==1.0.2                     cssutils==1.0.2
                                  > docutils==0.13.1
enum34==1.1.6                       enum34==1.1.6
                                  > futures==3.0.5
idna==2.5                           idna==2.5
ipaddress==1.0.18                   ipaddress==1.0.18
                                  > jmespath==0.9.2
lxml==3.8.0                         lxml==3.8.0
Mako==1.0.6                         Mako==1.0.6
MarkupSafe==1.0                     MarkupSafe==1.0
ndg-httpsclient==0.4.2              ndg-httpsclient==0.4.2
nimbus==1.1.7                       nimbus==1.1.7
packaging==16.8                     packaging==16.8
premailer==3.0.1                    premailer==3.0.1
pyasn1==0.2.3                       pyasn1==0.2.3
pycparser==2.17                     pycparser==2.17
pyOpenSSL==17.0.0                   pyOpenSSL==17.0.0
pyparsing==2.2.0                    pyparsing==2.2.0
                                  > python-dateutil==2.6.0
                                  > PyYAML==3.12
requests==2.17.3                    requests==2.17.3
                                  > rsa==3.4.2
                                  > s3transfer==0.1.10
sh==1.12.14                         sh==1.12.14
six==1.10.0                         six==1.10.0
urllib3==1.21.1                     urllib3==1.21.1
```

Comment: It complains about loading the private key for a certificate. Comparing your CA store is unrelated to that. Check your code where it tries to load the private key from and compare these files instead. Apart from the the `cert` parameter for `requests.get` should not be the CA bundle but a client certificate (and key). The CA bundle should be given in the `verify` parameter.

Comment: Thanks - that clearly fishy (and in fact completely wrong) requests.get() call was changed by someone else and I was looking right past it (it's been a while since I worked on that bit of code, and the other person shouldn't have been touching it). I was fixating on all the references that say the issue is signature of something ssl library version related. Your nudge was exactly what I needed to get out of my tunnel vision. Much appreciated!

(Embarrassingly, I was so fixated on the ssl library angle that it didn't occur to me that someone might have changed that code, and I didn't diff.)

Comment: If you want to put your comment in as an answer I'll happily accept it!